# Roblox API rejecting my question with 403? No further information

Tags: roblox

I'm using roproxy instead of roblox to get around cord measures, requestbody is username,ctype ,password and useridand for the headers I'm just doing xcrs token:xcrs.  It's just returning 403(). Is this an xcrs token thing? Couldn't find anything about it online.
Ideally, it would print the incorect password error, or anything but 403() 0
heres the code im using

```
   const passwordcheck = {
   ctype: "Username",
    cvalue: "usernametomyaccount",
    password: "passwordtomyaccount",
    captchaToken: "CaptchaFromFuncaptcha",
    captchaId: "Captcha",
    captchaprovider: "PROVIDER_ARKOSE_LABS",
    userId: 889124,
  };

  const request = {
    method: "POST",

    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "X-csrf-token": "wiXzYTbS/xF3",
      Cookie: "",
      
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(passwordcheck),
  };
```

the url is roproxy v2 login

I've tried using different proxies, but nothing came off it. Filling out the requestbody with all the stuff in the Roblox auth documentation didn't work either.

Comment: @Kylaaa Im using an xscrf token i grabbed from the roblox home page for testing.  For the headers i just have the csrf and content type. and for the body  i just have ctype  cvalue and password and userid. The network tab dosent say what im supposed to fill out in the headers and requestbody. Says token validation failed. I dont know what other tokens i need other than csrf